# Can I change the parent class of context in antlr4

Tags: java, antlr4

In antlr4  . Context's default parent class is ParserRuleContext. I want to add my some vars in Context. but I don't want to modify the ParserRuleContext.java。so I want to create a new Java class(e.g. MyParserRuleContext), which has a parent class ParserRuleContext, and Context class inherits from the new Class。

e.g.test.v4

expression: expression '..' Identifier '(' expressionList? ')'|...|...;

the production will make an ExpressionContext class。  ExpressionContent's parent class is MyParserRuleContext。 MyParserRuleContext's parent class is ParserRuleContext

can do this in test.v4???

Answer (score 3):

If you want actually want to do is associate additional data with your context objects, you can use `ParseTreeProperty<T>` objects to annotate your context objects.  Here's a simple example in a parse tree listener (in C#, but should be pretty similar in Java):

```
private ParseTreeProperty<Scope> ScopeAnnotations = new ParseTreeProperty<Scope>();
private Scope _currentScope = new GlobalScope();

public override void EnterBlockStmt(MyParser.BlockStmtContext context)
{
    InnerScope innerScope = new InnerScope(_currentScope);
    _currentScope = innerScope;

    ScopeAnnotations.Put(context, _currentScope);
}
```

Here, we've annotated a `BlockStmtContext` object with a `Scope` object, associating that scope object with the context object.

Later on, when you want to look up the `Scope` object associated with the context, you can write code like this (this is in a parse tree visitor):

```
public override SomeObject VisitBlockStmt(MyParser.BlockStmtContext context)
{
    SomeObject somethingOrOther;
    _currentScope = ScopeAnnotations.Get(context);

    ...
    do something useful with the scope object
    ...

    return somethingOrOther;
}
```

In general, I have found parse tree annotation to be extremely useful, as it allows you to carry the information to subsequent phases of compilation, such as in the example above.

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible. You can add a feature request to the issue tracker:
https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues

Or a comment on this related issue:
[#30: add rule context object factory?](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/30)

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but this is possible now (4.8), just define

```
options {
  contextSuperClass=<<your class name>>;
}
```

in parser grammar